# Regex: matching between underscores

Tags: regex, regex-group

For example, I have a string `111352_01_2_SAMPLE_TEXT_SAMPLE`. I need to match first, second, third number and remaining text.

Currently I have this:

- First number: `^[^_]+(?=_)` (Everything until 1. underscore)
- Second number: `(?<=_)[^_]*(?=_)` (Everything between 1. and 2. underscore)
- Remaining text: `(?:.*?_){3}(.*)\s*` (Text after third occurrence of underscore)

Is there any more "readable" way of building expression, since the logic for first three matches in quite similar.
And what's the best way of writing expression for matching everything

Comment: What you mean, you want to *extract*?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri meant to match

Comment: So you want to match any String which has first three characters numeric, and then the remaining text any string?

Comment: Can't you just match `[^_]+` and extract the first, second and third occurrences? You could also split by `_`.

Comment: I need four separate expressions, the story is that I provide regex expression for each _variable_. I'd like to avoid writing totally different expressions since from looking at text they do very similar job.

Comment: Are you using some SQL? "Readable" way depends on the language you are coding in.

Comment: I'm using Geoserver that needs a regex for each variable to parse from filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged `regex-group` I think a more straightforward way of retrieving these three substring could be:

```
^(.*?)_(.*?)_.*?_(.*)$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3MMS9/9)

---

Maybe you are looking to get a single regex expressions that is applicable to whichever element from the string you want. In that case you could use:

```
^(?:.*?_){0}([^\n_]+)
```

This is a zero-index type of retrieving elements delimited by an underscore. However, I do not see the benefit over a regular `split()` function. Change the zero to a 1, 2 or 3 etc.

Comment: If I change it to `^(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)$` I get correct matches as groups. But I still need separate expressions for each group only.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. Excuse me. Thought you wanted a single more readable way to capture those three bulletpoints you mentioned.

Comment: The second solution works for me.
Reason for not using split() is that I'm only providing regex to another program and I don't have any other way of changing logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
^(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qLMpAl/1/).